# External connection (internet) slow after connecting device to another network then back to main network

Tags: networking, mac, connection

I have a Draytek router set to use Google DNS at work. When I am at work and my Mac is connected to the network, in network settings > DNS I can see that I am connected using Google DNS.

The problem is that if I take my laptop home at night and then bring it back in the morning, it seems to make the connection really slow. But it is fine for all other users who haven't taken their machines off the network overnight. I believe it is a DNS issue, but from what I can see it all seems fine.

I do not have this problem when returning home from work.
At home my router is set to use the DNS server of my ISP.

The cure seems to be to restart my computer, but this is quite long to do each morning. Any ideas as to what the issue may be and how to resolve it ?

I tried renewing the DHCP lease, but that does not resolve the problem.

Comment: (1) Question: Is the laptop also slow to connect to your home network ? (2) Try to [Flush the DNS Cache](https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-flush-dns-in-mac-os-x/).

Comment: In my experience, this sounds like a lack of bandwidth.  Check Activity Monitor for high network usage (such as an update, download, etc).  If your workplaces' network is configured with a Quality of Service engine it may be choking your mac's available bandwidth so it won't impede on others traffic. (A lot of speculation here but worth a shot)

Comment: Do work and home have the same IP range/subnet?

Comment: @harrymc - 1) No, 2) ive just run the cache flush and will run it again next time i see the issue, i also noticed my home is on another DNS server (question updated) so that might be somthing to do with it. @ c0deuous - no @ JohnnyVegas - work is on 192.168.10.1 home is 192.168.1.1 both using 255.255.255.0

Comment: What about IPv6? Maybe at your home it is capable of connecting to servers via IPv6, but not so at work. So at work it tries to contact a server via its IPv6-address, times out, then retries at the IPv4 address. I had this problem in my network, where all IPv6 was blocked at the edge, but the windows machine thought it could use it because inside the network it got automatically configured as if IPv6 were a viable protocol. Disabling the IPv6 network stack on the machine fixed the issue.

Comment: why not log off and log on instead of restart?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use two wireless networks, my home and university, to browse Internet.

In my university I have been assigned a specific IP address and connect to the Internet through a proxy server where as at home I simply let my router assign me settings via DHCP. On a Mac, it is really easy to make a profile for a specific network rather than input the settings manually every time (Windows eh..) we are in a different network. We can make as many network profiles as we need to and assign the network settings in them. So whenever you go to the particular location, just select the profile from the network preference pane. It’s that simple!

**Let’s see how:**

**1.** Select the ‘Network’ pane from System Preferences.

[image: Picture 7]

**2.** In the ‘Locations’ drop down menu, select the option ‘Edit Locations’.

**3.** Then Click on the little + symbol and type in the location’s name.

[image: Picture 2]

[image: Picture 1]

**4.** Now click on the ‘Advanced’ button and the settings for Airport pop up. In the TCP/IP section enter your IP address and Subnet
    Mask.

[image: Picture 4]

**5.** Enter the Domain Name Server address in the DNS section.

[image: Picture 5]

**6.** If you network uses proxies to browse Internet, change those settings in the ‘Proxies’ tab.

[image: Picture 6]

**7.** Click Ok and then Apply. Next time whenever you want to switch
    network location, just select it from the locations menu in the
    Network preference pane.

**Setting up the same interface for two networks**

The default Automatic location does not accommodate having two configurations for using the same network interface in two different locations. For example, if you used your Ethernet port configured manually at work but via DHCP at home, the Automatic location will not let you avoid switching locations in its default state--you would need to switch locations.